# Unzip an archive that was split into 2 files

Tags: macos, unix, compression, zip

I have 2 zip files that were split using:

```
zip -r -s 15 my_file.zip my_file.pdf
```

Now I have 2 files:

- `my_file.zip`
- `my_file.z01`

How can I unzip them?

Doing `unzip my_file.zip` I get:

```
Archive: my_file.zip
waring (my_file.zip) zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
  attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
  together in order.  Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support
  doesn't exist yet (coming soon).
file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  4
```

Comment: Try to open the first file first, my_file.z01?

Answer (score 5):

zip doesn't support unzipping split files (bizarrely) so first you have to "fix" them on the receiving end.

```
zip -F my_file.zip --out unsplit.zip
```

This will get all files from the `my_file.z*` split archives and copy them into a new zip called `unsplit.zip` (or whatever you want).

You can then unzip this file as normal.

Comment: wow this was helpful. But not completely, I had 6 files zipped and then splitted and sent. When I tried this approach it recovered 2 files but for 4 other it gave this error - invalid compressed data to inflate. These are the commands I tried - `zip -F my_file.zip --out unsplit.zip` and then `unzip unsplit.zip`

Comment: in fact when I tried -FF it gives out the following for one of file - `copying: DSC_0073.MOV  (247424872 bytes)
 zip warning: entry truncated: DSC_0073.MOV` which explains why it is not getting unzipped, is it coz of the size of the file